# Users being asked to Consent Everytime Azure AD Application

Tags: azure-active-directory

I have an Azure AD Application that is written in Angular 2. The application is working fine as I can login against AD and get access tokens back. However the issue is that I am getting a consent request every time I login. Here is what the request looks like

```
        "https://login.microsoftonline.com/" + this.tenantId + "/oauth2/authorize?" +
        "response_type=id_token+token&" +
        "response_mode=fragment&" +
        "client_id=" + this.clientId + "&" +
        "redirect_uri=" + encodeURIComponent(window.location.href) + "/&" +
        "scope=openid&" +
        "state=" + this.state + "&" +
        "resource=" + encodeURIComponent(this.appuri) + "&" +
        "nonce=" + this.nonce;
```

This send me to the Azure Login Screen with the consent dialoag like so

[image]

I click accept and am directed back to where I want to go and everything is great. If I login again, I get the same prompt. What step do I need to take on the Azure AD side to store the consent of the user?
 Is it something in the manifest?

Comment: Where did you register you app from [old Azure portal](https://manage.windowsazure.com/) or the [V2.0 endpoint](https://apps.dev.microsoft.com/Disambiguation?ru=https%3a%2f%2fapps.dev.microsoft.com%2f )? And were you developing an multi-tenant app?

Comment: Check in the "Applications my company uses" field of AD => Applications.
If this application gets registered in the AD, to which the signed in user belongs to, consent page would not come again. 
Your application is not getting registered in the AD on granting the consent.

Comment: @fei-xue-msft I registered the app on portal.azure.com in the AD area. Yes it is multitenant but I have only consented for one company so far, actallu the same account which is an admin.

Comment: @RahulMohan my app is in that list in manage.windowsazure.com. What else could be the issue?

Comment: @FeiXue-MSFT Using the other method (apps.dev) gives other errors

Comment: @Lsaac Levin What's the value of parameter `this.appuri`?

Answer (score 3):

The consent screen you are seeing is the "admin consent screen" which should only appear if you pass "prompt=admin_consent" as a query string for the login url.

At the same time, if you pass this query string, you will be prompted to consent to the application each time. Instead, you want to make sure that you only pass this query string one time (the first time a user uses the app) and once it has been consented, make sure you are not passing any "prompt" query strings.

I hope this solves your problem!